# TNS-12541: TNS:no listener on entering ./sqlplus anju/XXXX@999.000.0.000/ORA12C

Tags: oracle, listener, tns, ora-12541

I get the listener error when I run this command:-

```
 ./sqlplus anju/XXXX@999.000.0.000/ORA12C
```

I did start my listener still it doesn't work.

```
SNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 – Production on 14-MAY-2020 10:21:14

Copyright (c) 1991, 2016, Oracle. All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=999.000.0.000)(PORT=1539)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
————————
Alias LISTENER
Version TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 – Production
Start Date 14-MAY-2020 10:12:47
Uptime 0 days 0 hr. 8 min. 27 sec
Trace Level off
Security ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP OFF
Listener Parameter File /ora01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File /ora01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/server/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary…
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=999.000.0.000)(PORT=1539)))
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=server)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=/ora01/app/oracle/admin/orcl/xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary…
Service “ORA12CXDB” has 1 instance(s).
Instance “ORA12C”, status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service…
Service “a50ca342f86bccc0e0536801a8c085de” has 1 instance(s).
Instance “ORA12C”, status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service…
Service “orcl” has 1 instance(s).
Instance “ORA12C”, status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service…
Service “orclpdb” has 1 instance(s).
Instance “ORA12C”, status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service…
The command completed successfully
```

and if I run the below command I get the same error:-

```
./sqlplus anju/XXXXX@999.000.0.000/ORA12C

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu May 14 10:34:59 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle. All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

this is my listener.ora file:-

LISTENER =
(DESCRIPTION_LIST =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 999.000.0.000)(PORT = 1539))
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
)
)
```

Could you please help..!!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use `code` tags for code and mask sensitive information like user credentials and IP

Comment: You are using a non-default-listener-port (1539) so you need to specify port: sqlplus user/pass@hostname:1539/ORA12C

Comment: @BjarteBrandt      I get this error after adding the port number.ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor

Comment: Your db instance (mem+processes) is named ORA12C. Your db instance exposes services named: "ORA12CXDB", "orcl", "orclpdb" so your connect string will be something like: sqlplus user/pass@hostname:1539/SERVICE_NAME

Comment: @BjarteBrandt I changed it to Service name instead of SID. And it works when I execute sqlplus command.Should we change this in the connection string also if we are connecting to database from an application?

Comment: Congrats! Yes, you need to point your application to the correct combination of dbnode, port and database service exactly the same way as with sqlplus.